# VBA Validation Throws 1004 Application -Defined Error

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have the following code which is triggered for thousands of cells. It adds a validation list to each cell (the list values are defined in a names range - the names range is in a separate tab).

```
Sub CreateList(cell As Variant, rng As String)
     If rng <> Empty Then
          With cell.Validation
             .Delete
             .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=" & rng
             .ShowError = False
          End With
       End If
    End Sub
```

I call the subroutine from another function which loops through cells. Note `totalCols` & `totalRow`s are set elsewhere but are the bounds of the data range:

```
    For i = 2 To totalRows
       For J = 1 To totalCols
          CreateList(Worksheets("Data").cells(i, j), GetRange(Worksheets("Data").cells(1, J).Value)
       Next
    Next
```

GetRange() takes a heading value (stored in row 1 of the "Data" sheet) and returns a range name (stored in a separate worksheet in the same workbook):

```
Function GetRange(cell As Variant) As String    
       If cell.Value = "Column One Name" Then
          GetRange = "RangeOne"
       ElseIf cell.Value = "Column Two Name" Then
          GetRange = "RangeTwo"
       Else
          GetRange = ""
       End If
End Sub
```

When I run the code it sometimes fails with an application defined error 1004. The peculiar thing here is at different points for different datasets. The larger the dataset the less columns it formats. With small datasets (i.e. 1/2 rows) it works - as in it loops through all ranges and adds lists accordingly.

**SOME MORE INFO:** The datasheet is not locked. When debugging, `rng` has the correct value. This is confirmed when doing an "Add Watch" in debug mode and checking the range values property of the range. The named range is within workbook scope but is contained in a separate worksheet.

It always stops in the same place when running for the first time for same data sets. It gets half way down a column sometimes populating the cells with the right range values and then just stops with error 1004.

When running for the second time immediately after the first fail - it sometimes stops in the very first cell requiring validation and displays the 1004 error. When this happens, it stops in the first cell requiring adding of validation for any data set. It's as if it breaks the worksheet at this point.

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: It fails on the Validation.Add line

Comment: Can you add a counter to `createlist` to see how many cells it successfully applys `DV` to? and test on a couple of your datasets.

Comment: Run 1: Failed - Counter = 65514; 
Run 2: Passed - Counter = 70553; 
Run 3: Failed - Counter = 65514; 

All were run against different datasets

Comment: It just failed on a separate datset with counter = 81343

Comment: when it fails for the first time - it stops at the first validation.add when running against another dataset (i.e. counter = 0 and program terminates). I have to close the excel file and reopen to rerun properly.

Comment: validation type is done on a column basis . Each column has a different range assigned to it. How would I go about assigning validation to an entire column starting from row X to the last row in that column?

Comment: Have you considered adding your validation to entire ranges in one shot (or at least not cell by cell)? Seems like you could assign all the cells in each row at once, since the list only depends on the value of the first cell. That's also going to be much faster...

Comment: Sorry misread your code - same thing applies though: loop through your columns and apply validation to each column.  I will try to make an edit to show how it could be done.

Comment: I think it's something to do with the call stack being full? I have 17, 000 rows and 49 columns, of which 25 columns require validation adding to them. It seems to be a problem with the mechanics of excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub ApplyValidation()

    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Worksheets("Data").Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, totalCols).Cells
        With c.Offset(1, 0).Resize(totalRows - 1, 1).Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=" & GetRange(c)
            .ShowError = False
        End With
    Next c

End Sub

Function GetRange(cell As Variant) As String
    If cell.Value = "Column One Name" Then
       GetRange = "RangeOne"
    ElseIf cell.Value = "Column Two Name" Then
       GetRange = "RangeTwo"
    Else
       GetRange = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives a 1004 on the Add line. It halts when trying to add verification to the first cell.

Comment: Edited my answer - issue was in the call to `GetRange()`

Comment: Unfortunately, after making this change, excel still chokes at the "Add" line for the very first cell in the first column

Comment: I just ran this on a 30,000 row x 100 col range and it was OK (and fast).  I did have a typo in `GetRange()` (`End Sub` instead of `End Function`)